# Why are attached properties stored as class variables?

Tags: .net, wpf, attached-properties

In WPF, to set the vertical location of an ellipse, for instance, one uses the method  `Canvas.SetTop(ellipseObj, y)`. That is to say, the location is stored in the *class* Canvas and *not* in the *canvas object* that contains the ellipse!

I like to understand why! So, *why* are attached properties stored as class variables?

Comment: MSDN has a comprehensive [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). And it's a misunderstanding that the location is *stored* in the Canvas class. Canvas just defines the property. The storage is somewhere deep inside the WPF dependency property system. You might think of it as a dictionary that stores property values for DependencyObject instances.

Answer (score 2):

The point of WPF is, that UI `Panels` decide where their child elements are drawn. So, controls themselves have no say about where they can be positioned. In measure pass of UI layout, only control's size is considered.

In your case, you are using `Canvas` as example, which is quite short-sighted. Canvas is only one of the few possible ways to layout child controls and only it was designed to allow precise positioning of it's child elements. So it makes sense to be able to set Top and Left values for each child. And just to note, Canvas is least-advised way to layout your UI.

But in `Grid`, no such thing is possible. Here, you set which `Row`, `Column` and what `RowSpan` and `ColSpan` should child have. And in `DockPanel`, you have different ways to dock the child elements.

And other panels like `StackPanel` and `WrapPanel` have no such options.

To solve this, you have 2 options:

1. Save all of those in each element. This will result in many unused properties AND lack of extensibility. What if someone wants to implement their own Panel, that layouts children differently and needs some other kind of property for each child?
2. Save those properties in container itself. This gives you space saving AND option to extend the whole thing.

Also, [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) are useful for many other things, than panel layout.

Comment: After typing this answer, I noticed I don't answer the question. Guess I will leave it here then.

Answer (score 1):

Attached properties are implemented that way so that any framework element (say a Line, or a TextBox) can be given a relationship to another object (say a Canvas, or a Grid), that it knows nothing about.  Properties like `Left` and `Top` correctly belong to the container control, which is responsible for arranging its child element.

You can think of it like a [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) -- the Canvas container is able to effectively modify the behavior of any child elements, without actually changing the structure of those elements.

Here's how the [MSDN article on attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) explains it:

> One purpose of an attached property is to allow different child elements to specify unique values for a property that is actually defined in a parent element.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Intuitively, I think the top-property of an ellipse should be stored in the Canvas object, the container. But why is it stored in the canvas Class?

Comment: @ragnarius it's *defined* in the Canvas class, because you wouldn't want to define it at one of the base classes like FrameworkElement. But it's *stored* in the target (hence "attached")